# Intent to play a video always plays the same one

Tags: android

I am creating an intent to play videos stored in the sdcard. It happens that I play the first one, everything is OK. But when I play another one, it just plays everytime the first one I played. Here is my code:

```
    package com.remote;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.remote.R.drawable;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;


    public class MyVideos extends Activity{

private String path="/sdcard/Movies/Telmex";



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myvideos);

    createLinks(new File(path));

}

public void createLinks(File path) 
{ 
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myvideoslayout);
    if( path.exists() ) {
        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) 
        {
          if(files[i].getName().toString().charAt(0)!='.')
          {
           String videoName;
           Button video=new Button(this);
           video.setBackgroundColor(2);
           video.setTextSize(23);
           video.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,drawable.videoicon,0);
           videoName=new String(files[i].getName());
           video.setText(videoName);
           createListener(video,videoName);
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
           );   
           layout.addView(video,p); 
          }

        }
    }
}

public void createListener(Button video, final String name)
{
    video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            videoPlayer(path,name,true);
        }
    }); 
}

public void videoPlayer(String path, String fileName, boolean autoplay)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri data = Uri.parse(path+"/"+fileName);
    intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/mp4");
    startActivity(intent);



 }

  }
```

Comment: Solved! what I've done is using the example you told me: http://sree.cc/google/android/playing-the-video-in-sd-card-of-android

I had to use the two Activity way in order to get it working in portrait mode in the list, and in landscape in the player. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rewrite**

I did some digging and wrote the code below, if this has the same problem then it is your external video player not you app.

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
    // Change this path
    private final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/android/data/com.example/files/";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        File dir = new File(path);
        List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
        Collections.addAll(files, dir.list());
        Collections.sort(files);

        while(files.get(0).startsWith("."))
            files.remove(0);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, files);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String uri = path + ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(uri), "video/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Addition**

I'm glad the internal video player works. The reason why it resets is that every time you change orientation the OS destroys and rebuilds your app from scratch...  It's the same as if you exited the app by pressing the back button and ran it again. If you are using the tutorial from below, you need to save the video's location in `onDestroy()` to a class variable and in your `onCreate()` check to see if that variable has a valid location or just start at the beginning of the video.

Comment: Do your button have different text?

Comment: It happens that when I go back and choose a different one, the player resumes the previous video where it was. But even if I let it finish and I choose a new one. It plays the same one again no matter what.

Comment: Ahh, I get it. Have you verified that a different fileName is passed to the intent?

Comment: yes, it is always the corresponding fileName. What is happening is that the video player doesn't play the new one, it just continues the older.

Comment: it throws me an ActivityNotFoundException now. Should I add something to the manifest?

Comment: Make sure you have the right import files; clean build and crtl+shift+o in Eclipse.

Comment: Any luck? Unless your app is playing the video you shouldn't need to add any intent filters. Here is a [video selector / player tutorial](http://sree.cc/google/android/playing-the-video-in-sd-card-of-android) if you want to go that route.

Comment: My question now is: as I am generating a new Activity, lets say dynamically, shouldn't I add it to the manifest? if so, what would be it's name?

Comment: If you only want to launch another app, then no your manifest doesn't need any extra intent filters.